# How to check if file exist in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, relative-path

I am working on an `ASP.NET MVC 4` application. I allow users to upload files but I want to save them with different name on the server so I created helper method which should return `GUID` to be used. Even though it probably will never happen still I want to check if I have a file with the same `GUID` name so I have this as code :

```
public static string GetUniqueName(string pathToFile)
        {
            bool IsUnique = false;
            string guid = null;

            while (!IsUnique)
            {
                guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
                var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathToFile, "login.jpg");

                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                {
                    IsUnique = true;
                }
            }

            return guid;
        }
```

as you can see the name of the file is hard coded just for testing purposes, because I know there is such file.

To save the file I use this:

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/NewsImages"), fileName);
```

and it's working properly. So when I tried to call my static method I pass the arbument like this:

```
string test = Helper.GetUniqueName("~/Content/NewsImages");
```

but then in debug I saw that

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(pathToFile, "login.jpg");
```

returns `~/Content/NewsImages\\login.jpg` so I decided to change the argument that I pass to:

```
string test = Helper.GetUniqueName("~\\Content\\NewsImages");
```

which now results in `~\\Content\\NewsImages\\login.jpg` which seems fine but then in:

```
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                IsUnique = true;
            }
```

I pass the check, even though I know that such a file exist in the directory that I want to check. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When calling the helper method you should use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this will convert from a virtual path to a physical path e.g.

```
string test = Helper.GetUniqueName(Server.MapPath("~/Content/NewsImages"));
```

Comment: Thanks, It fix the paths. Now it's returning the correct result accordingly.